# For each positive integer n and graph H, find ex(n, H’) in terms of ex(n, H).

Tags: graph-theory

Let H be any graph, and let H’ be the graph with V(H’) = V(H) U {v} for some vertex v not in V(H), and E(H’) = E(H). For each positive integer n and graph H, find ex(n, H’) in terms of ex(n, H).
I'm new to the Graph Theory and totally lost when doing this assignment.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What does "ex" mean, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The extremal number

Comment: OK. And, what does that mean?

Comment: Consider the cases $n < |V(H')|$ and $n \ge |V(H')|$ separately, and don't overthink it. Remember you don't have to figure out $\text{ex}(n, H)$, just how $\text{ex}(n, H')$ is related to it. If $G$ has a subgraph isomorphic to $H$, what else must be true for it to have a subgraph isomorphic to $H'$?